# Retrieving similar frames

Tags: neural-networks

I have N images in database and K images as test images, N > K always and N is much larger in size. I have extracted CNN embeddings from all the images (both images which are in database and test images) and created arrays. Array sizes are NxM and KxM where M is the CNN embeddings size. Is there any way i can retrieve the K matched/similar frames directly from N database images using the above two arrays?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could find the nearest neighbor in your database for each test image. Standard L2 distance or cosine similarity should work well.

Comment: yes i have tried using cosine similarity for each test image which works quite good. But i am looking for any methametical formula through which i can get correlation between two arrays with position of test frames matched index in database of frames array. As i might have many test cases with varying no.of frames and many database of frames ex: many KxM arrays and many NxM arrays, so if i can find directly correlation between a test case of frames array i.e. a KxM sized with many NxM sized database of frames. so that a test case might be good match at one of the NxM arrays.